# Energy consumption of an algorithm in c code

Tags: c, energy

I need to calculate the energy consumption of an algorithm in c code. Any ideas how this can be done and if there are pre-defined functions for that?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Some hits from https://www.google.com/search?q=energy+consumption+of+software: https://peerj.com/preprints/886/ https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00912613/document

Comment: (Algorithms don't consume energy: processes do.)

Answer (score 0):

It is nigh impossible to do it from C code alone. The multiple ways a C-compiler is allowed to translate a chunk of C-code do not allow for a precise calculation of the energy consumption. You need to know how the compiler translates which code for which architecture.

It is much simpler (for certain degrees of "simple") to count the assembler commands and multiply them with the respective latencies (Listed in the technical specs, e.g. for a randomly chosen MCU from the Wiki list: http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc32002.pdf). This is still not exact, division for example might take a different amount of CPU cycles depending on the input, CPU architecture and implementation in the hardware, but it comes quite close and is rather simple, although a bit tedious.

And than there are the loops with a completely unknown number of iterations, input taking different paths with different runtimes and much more. The people writing encryption software know more about it, especially how to avoid it. You might not like their solutions.

Otherwise: check what you expect for input (you *do* know which path which input takes, do you?), write a test program, go to e.g.: https://www.rohde-schwarz.com/ to get a good meter and measure the power consumption. You also need an engineer who knows how to do that, it's not easy!